# Playing two sound simultaneously with loop c#

Tags: c#, windows-media-player

I have a background music, and a button that's playing a 1~2 second sound effect.
what i want is to make it so that the background music will still continue to play even after the button sound is played.

Currently, it's stopping the background music permanently to play the sound button.

This is the current solution i have now

```
private void LoginGUI_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        string filename = @"..\..\Soundtracks\The Boy Who Shattered Time.wav";
        Player = new System.Media.SoundPlayer(filename);
        Player.PlayLooping();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Unable to play soundtrack.");
    }
}
```

And here's the button

```
public virtual void getButtonSound()
{
    try
    {
        string filename = @"..\..\Soundtracks\demacia.wav";
        Player = new System.Media.SoundPlayer(filename);
        Player.PlaySync();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Unable to play soundtrack.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use thread

```
new System.Threading.Thread(() => {
        var c = new System.Windows.Media.MediaPlayer();
        c.Open(new System.Uri(@"..\..\Soundtracks\The Boy Who Shattered Time.wav"));
        c.PlayLooping();
    }).Start();


new System.Threading.Thread(() => {
        var c = new System.Windows.Media.MediaPlayer();
        c.Open(new System.Uri(@"..\..\Soundtracks\demacia.wav"));
        c.Play();
    }).Start();
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to work, it's saying that the brackets in .thread(() must have something, so i put in a dummy value, but now it's saying that my url is invalid. also "using System.Windows.Media.MediaPlayer" doesn't seem to work for me

Answer (score 0):

I guess `Player` is a field of your class, so you are overwriting the first instance containing the looping wav file with your button sound. Use two instances of `SoundPlayer` - one for each sound - and there should be no need for threads.

Also you should change `PlaySync()` to `Play()`, because `Play()` and `PlayLooping()` will use threads internally, while `PlaySync()` will block the current thread.